# 2020 Mazda MX3 - How to reset infotainment system without physical power disconnect?

Tags: mazda, infotainment

I have (well, my girlfriend has) a 2020 Mazda MX3. It lets me plug an android phone into USB1 and mirror the Waze screen from the phone to the screen on the center console.

After some weeks, this stops working. The fix, which is known to work, is to remove the glovebox and disconnect/reconnect power to the car's entertainment system.

This is... a hassle.

a) Is there a general fix?
--- Can I update firmware in the car, or something?

b) Is there a way I can reboot the car's system via its menus or such, without needing to physically disconnect power?

c) Is there some other solution?

d) Where else should I post this question?